# Cloud VPN's removal of restriction on peer's IKE identity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I am using a VPN tunnel with IKE version ikev2. I received an email from GCP team regarding "**Cloud VPN's removal of restriction on peer's IKE identity may require you to take action**"
In the What do I need to do? section it recommends to use ikev1.

- Please review the following options to see which one applies to your
  specific case: If you are using Yamaha RTX800-series or Yamaha
  RTX1200-series routers, please upgrade to the latest firmware from
  Yamaha or recreate your tunnels using IKEv1 before June 15, 2022.

Should I have to change the ike version from v2 to v1 .? Can someone guide me through this?

Comment: Are you using the specified Yamaha routers? If yes, upgrade their firmware. Edit your question with details on the router and firmware version.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions in this email are applicable only if your tunnels have been **unestablished** due to the peer identity restriction:

> Once we apply this change, some tunnels which previously failed to be
> established, might become established. Successfully established tunnels
> will be unaffected by this change.

If you tunnels are established, this change will have no impact.
There is no need to downgrade the IKE version since both v1 and v2 are supported - [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/supported-ike-ciphers).